# How to get the intersection of geometry of two QWidgets with different parents?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

With Qt4 (here using PyQt4) to get the area of intersection of two QWidgets---and that's particularly useful with QRubberband when making a selection---one simply does:

`intersection = rubberband.geometry().intersected(mydocumentwidget.geometry())`

Now this assumes that `rubberband` and `mydocumentwidget` have the same parent widget, i.e. more precisely that their coordinates are relative to the same origin. This is because the method call is `QRect.intersected()` and `QRect` itself does not have a parent, it's a simple tuple with 4 integers and some method calls.

Now in my case `rubberband` and `mydocumentwidget` have the same parent, but I am interested in the interesection of the rubberband with mydocument's children, i.e. pages of the document.
Pages however take reference their coordinate to a different point on the screen.

How can I get to calculate the intersection between the rubberband and my page widgets? Is there a way to convert the coordinates to reference the parent's parent? I can of course just lay down the math myself, but I don't think it's very clean. Does Qt4 provide any means to convert this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is map the point of the QRect to the parent widget. You can map QPoints to various targets (parent, other, global), but since you specifically want to map to `mydocumentwidget`, here is what you do:

```
doc_child = getChildOfDocument() # pseudo
rect = doc_child.geometry()

mappedPoint = doc_child.mapToParent(rect.topleft())
# alternative #
# mappedPoint = doc_child.mapTo(mydocumentwidget, rect.topleft()) 

mappedRect = QtCore.QRect(mappedPoint, rect.size())
intersection = rubberband.geometry().intersected(mappedRect)
```

Comment: Thanks, so I can pass any widget ins this mapToParent()? That's cool. It would be nice if there was a simple way to get global geometry like QWidget.globalGeometry(), referring to the main window's origin.

Comment: @Benjamin: `mapTo(other, aPoint)` is for any widget. `mapToParent(aPoint)` maps the given point to this widgets parent (or global if none). There is also `QWidget.mapToGlobal(aPoint)`. But remember, global does not mean a main window. Global means the highest root in the app (could be screen coordinate). Main window is just another QWidget. Also, the reason there isn't a map specifically for QRect is because the size doesn't need to map. Just points.